# PHP PDO query execution don't save passed data

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I've a problem with PDO prepared statements using mysql.
When the query is executed it will save into the preposed table the placeholders that I've binded using the `bindParam()` method. 
Here is the code and here is a screen of the result of the execution of the query. How i can solve this embaracing problem? I'm a newbie on PDO!

PHP (This is the controller that is called using ajax).

```
if(isset($_POST['code'])){

$code = filter_var($_POST['code'],FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);    
$qty = filter_var($_POST['quantity'],FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);  
$brand = filter_var($_POST['brand'],FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$article_name = filter_var($_POST['artName'],FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);  
$price = filter_var($_POST['price'],FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$article_type = filter_var($_POST['artType'],FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING); 
$note = filter_var($_POST['note'],FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);    

$save = $core->insert_article($code,$qty,$brand,$article_name,$price,$article_type,$note);    

if($save){
echo 'ok';    
} else {
echo 'error';    
}

}
```

PHP 2 (this is the function of the class who manage all the database operations)

```
public function insert_article($code,$qty,$brand,$article_name,$price,$article_type,$note){

$db = $this->init_db();    

$sql = "INSERT INTO products (cod_articolo, pezzi_disponibili, marca, nome_articolo, prezzo, tipologia_articolo, note) VALUES (':cod_articolo',':pezzi_disponibili',':marca',':nome_prodotto',':prezzo',':tipologia_articolo',':note')";    
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);    

$stmt->bindParam(':cod_articolo',$code,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':pezzi_disponibili',$qty,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':marca',$brand,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':nome_articolo',$article_name,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':prezzo',$price,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':tipologia_articolo',$article_type,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':note',$note,PDO::PARAM_STR);

if($stmt->execute()){
echo 'ok';    
} else {
echo 'error';    
}    

}
```

This is the screen of the results after that the query is executed
[table after query execution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5GxG8.jpg)

Comment: Remove the single quotes enclosing your placeholders. You don't need those.

Comment: @KarloKokkak from the query placeholders?
I've tried but it will output an error "PHP Warning:  PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined ..."

Comment: Your placeholder is - `:nome_prodotto` - and your `bindParam()` argument is different - `:nome_articolo`

Comment: ok, thank you i will fix this mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing the single quotes surrounding the binding part

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO products (cod_articolo, pezzi_disponibili, marca, nome_articolo, prezzo, tipologia_articolo, note) VALUES (:cod_articolo,:pezzi_disponibili,:marca,:nome_prodotto,:prezzo,:tipologia_articolo,:note)";
```

Comment: ok, but  it will give me an error, PHP Warning:  PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/m/core.php on line 34.
The only parameter that I don't define is the id that is auto increment value.

Comment: Thank you for the support, I need to do more practice with PDO. I was able to solve the problem, and it was a mistake of mine. I will pay more attention when I write php code.